# ping is bypassing default gateway

Tags: openvpn, ufw

I have an ubuntu server 16.04 setup as an OpenVPN gateway on my network with the IP 192.168.10.14 going out over tun1

Any client that uses 192.168.10.14 as their gateway is sent out via the VPN tunnel to the internet. if I use ipleak.net every client has the IP of the VPN endpoint not my own IP

I have UFW setup on the VPN gateway (192.168.10.14) so that if i disable the VPN tunnel then any clients can no longer get to the internet as UFW only allows out over tun1

The problem i have is that if i disable the VPN tunnel on 192.168.10.14 then all the browsers stop working which is what i want. if they ping google.com there is no response which is what i want. but if they ping an IP address, say 8.8.8.8 then the ping still works, even though the gateway VPN is down. in the ping results i get

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=19.1 ms
From 192.168.10.14: icmp_seq=7 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.10.1)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=18.6 ms
```

where the 192.168.10.1 in the nexthop is my router. So the ping to the ip is ignoring the firewall rules on the VPN box, or the vpn box is forwarding it directly to the router for some reason

is there anything i can do on the VPN box to stop this. OR on the clients? i would prefer on the VPN machine os i dont have(or might not be able to) configure the clients

forwarding setup up on VPN box

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
#
# For IP Forwarding through PIA
#
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

ufw rules on VPN Box

```
To                              Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on tun1           (out)
[ 3] Anywhere                   ALLOW IN    192.168.10.0/24
[ 4] 1198/udp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                   (out)
```

route on vpn box (VPN Tunnel up)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.6.10.5       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.6.10.1       10.6.10.5       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun1
10.6.10.5       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
128.0.0.0       10.6.10.5       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun1
172.98.67.68    192.168.10.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

route on VPN box (VPN tunnel down)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

ping from VPN box to 8.8.8.8 (VPN tunnel down)

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

route on client machine

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.14   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Based on you question you do not cut internet access. You only cut dns resolving. Because of that you can ping `8.8.8.8`. If you want to can all traffic if tun interface is down, kill default route. For more you must provide  me output of commands from client when you are connected and you not connected `route -n`. Also I need `ufw` rules and routes from `VPN box`

Comment: i had an idea. if i add an up & down script to the vpn that disables ip forwarding would that work? as in stop any packets being forwarded through the vpn box

Answer (score 1):

Problem with "bypassing" occur because of default route on VPN box. Which is needed and cannot be deleted and ip forwarding is still enabled. Ip forwarding work based on interface, not ip address

Your `VPN box` is on `ip 192.168.10.14` and you can add insert `ufw` rule witch will be triggered when tunnel is down.

Add in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` some script to cut access from clients to your `VPN box`

Example:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-down.d/scriptdown
```

and put content

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "tun1" ] || exit 0
# cat access from client
sudo ufw insert 1 deny in on eth0 from 192.168.10.0/24 to 192.186.10.14
```

give `scriptdown` privilege

```
chmod 755 /etc/network/if-down.d/scriptdown
```

`if-down.d` will trigger script called `scriptdown` when `tun1` go `down` and will deny traffic from `192.168.10.0/24` to `192.168.10.14`

You need script to delete this rule when `tun1` is up

Add in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` script to allow access from clients to your `VPN box`

```
sudo nano /etc/network/if-up.d/scriptup
```

and put content

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "tun1" ] || exit 0
# cat access from client
sudo ufw delete 1
```

give `scriptup` privilege

```
chmod 755 /etc/network/if-down.d/scriptup
```

`if-up.d` will trigger script called `scriptup` when `tun1` go `up` and will allow traffic from `192.168.10.0/24` to `192.168.10.14`

Try.